# According to calculations why the current of a battery of a mobile is high?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, electric-circuits, power

If you pay attention to the features of your mobile's battery the voltage would be around 3-4V and power is 4-5 Wh (14400-18000 Ws) and with calculating the current you can find a very high number(P=V*I so I= about 4000 A).
How could it be possible?[image: in this case I=4680 A]

Comment: you are calculating the total current you would get if you could extract all the energy from the battery in one single second. it's theoretically sound but a cellphone battery can't be discharged as fast as that. however, some batteries you CAN discharge so you can melt metal if you short them :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exactly in trouble!
Wh is a symbol of ENERGY, not the POWER!

Answer (score 1):

The unit Wh, shown on the battery, is Watt hours, which is the total energy (Joules), not the power.